# Остановить запрос и вернуть другое значение если количество записей превышает число MS SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, запрос

Доброго времени. Возник вопрос, возможно ли в запросе проверить, содержит ли текущий(этот же) запрос определенное количество строк(т.е. он еще в процессе выполнения, но уже известно, что он вернет, например, 1000+ строк), и если содержит, то вместо выборки вернуть другой результат, например select 'To much results'.

Задача именно не в том, что бы выбрать с помощью count, а потом проверить и вывести, а динамически это узнавать

Comment: Известно только когда запрос заканчивается, он может перебирать миллионы записей и только в самом конце применить к ним какую нибудь склейку или просто условие (having, например) и от этого миллиона останется 2 записи или 1002 ... так что такого понятия как "уже понятно" в sql нет. ставите top 1000 и сами обрабатываете

Comment: Можно сохранять/кешировать агрегированные данные и делать __приблизительную__ оценку по этим агрегированным данным

Comment: Спасибо за ваш ответ. Дело в том, что я работаю над не оптимизированной БД, которая тяжело переносит именно мою логику, которую генерирует entityFramework (C#)

Answer (score 1):

Да это можно сделать. Но не путайте "праведное" с "грешным". Это нужно делать не в запросе. А перед ним. Зачем запускать тяжелый запрос на выполнение?

Допустим у Вас есть запрос такого вида:

```
SELECT `table1`.*
FROM `table1`
INNER JOIN `table2` ON (`table1`.`tb2_id` = `table2`.`id`)
...
```

Перед его выполнением делаете:

```
SELECT COUNT(`table1`.`id`)
FROM `table1`
INNER JOIN `table2` ON (`table1`.`tb2_id` = `table2`.`id`) // по возможности убирая излишние JOIN-ы
...
```

Comment: В общем случае решение кажется странным. Вместо 1го тяжелого запроса будут выполнены два тяжелых запроса.

Comment: Значит Вы не понимаете концепцию работы БД. Первый запрос выполнится быстрей в разы. Так как ему не нужно будет передавать данные, а всего лишь одно число. А второй выполнится за счет того что таблицы из первого запроса попадут в кэш MySQL-я. А если поумничать хотите, то оптимальности нет предела, делайте кучу смежных таблиц где храните количество ответов для каждого Вашего запроса. Вы просили совета или просто пофлудить хотели?

Comment: Поясните, что я понял не так. Есть тяжелый запрос, который хочется выполнять если он возвращает нужное количество строк, и убивать, если строк больше чем нужно. На основании желания его убивать предполагаю, что он тяжелый. Дальше Вы предлагаете заменить 1 запрос другим. Я не понимаю, по какой причине первый запрос выполнится в разы быстрее второго, поясните пожалуйста. И нигде не сказано, что основная нагрузка при запросе идет на дисковую подсистему. Я не говорю, что решение плохое, я говорю, что не понимаю почему оно хорошее в общем случае и прошу объяснить или отправить по ссылкам

Comment: @lDrakonl скачайте книгу и почитайте. Если условно все упростить запрос можно разбить на несколько частей. `1` - поиск запроса в кэше, `2` - загрузка нужных таблиц, `3` - выполнение самого запроса, `4` - подготовка данных для ответа. `5` - передача ответа. Мой запрос сэкономит Вам `4` и `5` этапы. Если количество записей Вас удволитворит, только тогда Вы выберете все данные по данному запросу (при этом экономя на пункте `2`).